# How to setup a button click on server side by using Google Tag manager?

Tags: triggers, tags, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I am creating a tag in the Google Tag Manager Server Side container but in trigger, I can't see a button click option like GTM web.
is that possible if yes then how to implement ??

Answer (score 1):

There are no buttons on the server side, so naturally backend GTM is unable to have triggers like that. Judging from the question, however, you don't quite understand what the server-side tag management is and you probably should not go that way.

Just in case you're sure you need server-side GTM, the button tracking with it would be sending a request from FE to BE when the click happens (assuming no such request is already sent) and then having BE to trigger an explicit GTM event for this button click.